# CS50 Caesar multiple errors

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on Caesar of CS50 and I don't know what's wrong with this code. I keep getting 5 errors and 1 warning (scroll down). I have done my best so far to fix it but I honestly don't know what to do.

The program is essentially a Caesar cipher encoder. When I launch the program it should as me for a key (which is a number) and the message I'm trying to cipher, it should then give me the output which is the cipher.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
bool check_valid_key(string s);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2 || !check_valid_key(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)
    {
        char c = plaintext[i];
        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            char m = 'A';
            if (islower(c))
                m = 'a';
            printf("%c", (c - m + key) % 26 + m);
        }
        else
            printf("%c", c);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

 bool check_valid_key(string s);
 {
     for (int i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `len = strlen(plaintext)`?

Comment: Is this C or C++?  The C language doesn't have a `string` type?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's a typedef for `char *` in `cs50.h`.

Comment: You should assign the length of the C-String to a temporary variable before the `for` loop.  The function `strlen` goes through each of the characters in the C-String, **each time it is called**, such a waste for a constant string.

Comment: You're missing parenthesis, `if islower(c)`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm doing so gives me an error on line 37 for expected identifier. Line 37 is the 6th last line.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it already has parenthesis. Also, I'm confused regarding your 2nd comment.

Comment: @VishG:  The syntax should be `if (islower(c))`.  There should be a parenthesis after the word `if`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that didn't make difference. I'm still getting the error on line 37 (6th last line) about expected identifier or '('

Comment: Compare the `for` statement in function `check_valid_key()` to the `for` statement in `main()`.  Notice anything different?

Comment: @VishG:  I'm doing a first pass code / syntax check.  See the last warning in your picture.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews there is a difference between the 'plaintext' and 's' but I think that's supposed to be there

Comment: Your program will gag if I pass "cheddar_cheese", as `argv[1]`, because you are only considering numeric digits as a bad text.

Comment: The difference is `int i, len < strlen` versus `int i, len = strlen`.

Comment: Then how can I fix that so it takes in numbers as well? get rid of isalpha?

Comment: In `main`, `for (int i = 0, len < strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)` --> `for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++)`

Comment: You should review your `get_string` function to see if it is returning a pointer to a local variable.  Local variables will disappear after exit and your pointer (a.k.a. `string`) will be invalid.  Try passing the address of the parameter and modifying the parameter.

Comment: @alex01011 No, what you posted is incorrect [and doesn't compile]. The correct fix is what I just posted in my previous comment.

Comment: @CraigEstey I already fixed what you had mentioned, I'm still getting 1 expected identifier or '(' error

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm doing this on a vm ide. All the stuff is store in the VM and in the directories. there is no way for me to change it.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon on line 36.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm this is what its giving me when I do that https://gyazo.com/3f48d5984e4cb6b853d16c64b0ea6dd4

Comment: Per _1201ProgramAlarm_, near the bottom, `bool check_valid_key(string s); {` --> `bool check_valid_key(string s) {`. After this fix [and the previous one I suggested], your program compiles and runs cleanly.

Comment: @CraigEstey what compiler are you using? In AWS C9 it gives me this error https://gyazo.com/3f48d5984e4cb6b853d16c64b0ea6dd4

Comment: @CraigEstey I tried using repl.it and its giving me the same error in that

Comment: That's a linker error (i.e. it can't find the `cs50` library). I have an older/outdated version somewhere, but I hand coded a `get_string` rather than futz with building/linking the library. You need (e.g.) `clang -o caesar caesar.c /path/to/cs50/lib.a`

Comment: @CraigEstey doing what you gave me give "no such file or directory". To which I did clang -o caesar caesar.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs50/libcs50/develop/src/cs50.c the link is for the raw file of the cs50 library and that gives the same error

Comment: What is the full path to the _local_ copy in your filesystem for `cs50.c`? (i.e.) The compiler does _not_ handle a URL. You have to do a `git clone` somewhere and use the files in your cloned directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it would be useful to use a better text editor to catch syntax errors before you even compile. here are the syntax errors your program has.

the `len` should be assigned first like this

```c
for (int i = 0, len = strlen(plaintext); i < len; i++) {
```

but that's in efficient since the `strlen()` is called at each iteration, do this instead.

```c
int len = strlen(plaintext); // it's in efficient to calculate length each iteration.
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

---

condition for if statements should be surrounded by brackets.

```c
if (islower(c)) // if (cond) <-- brackets are importants
```

---

your function definition has a semicolon which is also a syntax error

```c
bool check_valid_key(string s) // ; <-- remove this semicolon
{
}
```

Comment: Making all the changes you suggested gives me this https://gyazo.com/3f48d5984e4cb6b853d16c64b0ea6dd4

Comment: that function defined in `cs50.c`. you also need to add `cs50.c` when you compile

Comment: What do you mean? How can I do that? I'm sorry I'm new to this so I don't know much.

Comment: I've found the source in github cs50 program here https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.c or it may already in the sources they provide, search in the sources

Comment: I'm sorry but search for what in the srouces? I tried doing clang -o caesar caesar.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs50/libcs50/develop/src/cs50.c and that didn't work

Comment: search for `cs50.c` file and add that to your sources like `clang caesar.c cs50.c`

Comment: or maybe try `clang caesar.c -lcs50` to link against that library, (not sure, I'm not familiar with the program) if you can't find libcs50 you also need to provide a lib path with `-L` flag

Comment: Just cloned it and that worked. Thanks

Comment: Did so, upvoting the question would be greatly appreciated!